# What is the equivalent of curl --upload-file in node-request

Tags: node.js, curl, node-request

I'm using [node-request](https://github.com/request/request) and trying to send a file to IBM's HDFS, as per [this documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPT3X_3.0.0/com.ibm.swg.im.infosphere.biginsights.admin.doc/doc/admin_fileupload_rest_apis.html).

Passing this JSON object to request successfully uploads:

```
    var options = {
        method: 'put',
        body: 'foo',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
            'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'
        }
    };
```

And running this CURL command successfully uploads a file as well:

`curl -v -X PUT -L -b cookie.jar "https://host:port/webhdfs/v1/tmp/myLargeFile.zip?op=CREATE&data=true" --header "Content-Type:application/octet-stream" --header "Transfer-Encoding:chunked" -T "file.txt"`

However, trying to specify a file stream like so:

```
    var options = {
        method: 'put',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
            'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'
        }, 
        multipart : [
            { body: fs.createReadStream(localFile) }
        ]
    };
```

fails, and I don't know where I'm going wrong. How do I reproduce the '--upload-file' argument from CURL using node-request?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I threw up an [example on Github](https://github.com/scottlabs/testing-file-upload) that works.

The gist is that you need to pipe the file into Request:

```
fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(request.put(putURL,options,function(err, httpsResponse, body){
    if ( err ) {
        console.log('err', err);
    } else {
        console.log(body);
    }
}));
```

Still not sure how to pass in a file stream as an option in the options params but this will do for me!

-- UPDATE --

Wow, I feel like an absolute idiot. The option would be `file`. Yes, it's that simple.

Comment: Where would you specify a username and password for the remote url?